# How would you remove the malware from a router or switch?

Tags: malware, hardware, firmware

With the recent release of vault 7 was just wondering if you were to purchase a piece of network equipment off of eBay (or anything else for that matter?) that the CIA installed malware onto, how would you go about removing that?

Would a firmware reinstall be enough to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

If

- the installed malware is only present within the storage that gets
  overwritten by a firmware reinstall
- you can trust the firmware you're about to reinstall, and
- you can trust the mechanism by which you reinstall that firmware

then yes, it would be enough.

Comment: i don't see how the avg or even advanced user can possibly verify 1+3...

Comment: 1 can be verified by analysing the design - it's possible there's only one writeable storage chip in the device. Clearing this would remove all malware. Verifying 2 would likely require using something like JTAG.